# displaying pdf files in broser using php laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-4

hi im currently working on a project that entails displaying od pdf files in the browser. So basically i store my pdf files under public/uploads/docs and try to display the pdf using my current code below. Unfortunately, it is always saying 'failed to load pdf' as you can see i also dumped the address i should be going to so here it is

```
string(59) "uploads/docs/2016-05-23-22-05-57-oth-Laravel Cheatsheet.pdf"





<?php
        $pdf = 'uploads/docs/' . $list->filename;
        dd($pdfurl);
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        // header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $pdf . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdf));
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        @readfile($pdf);
        exit;
        ?>
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i just fixed my code and here is the working one :)

```
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($pdfurl);
        exit;
```